# Animate a layouts alpha

Tags: android, animation, layout

I have a layout that i am trying to animate. It initially has its visibility set to `GONE` with alpha 0.

I then use the following to animate it:

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_info);
layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
layout.bringToFront();    
final AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0F, 0.8F);
animation.setDuration(time);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
layout.startAnimation(animation);
```

But nothing happends. I have used the same code with a progressBar and i get the result i want. Why isnt it working for my layout?

I am animating it to come in front of another layout (if it isnt already) to act as an information screen hence the `bringToFront()`. **I would like to add that i have since deleted the bringToFront() and there is no change. So the problem is nothing to do with that.**

---

Edit: XML Code

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_custom5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_custom5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img_custom5"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/img_custom5"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/img_custom5"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/text_custom5"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:background="@color/color_black"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:minWidth="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/pleasewait"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your xml code ?

Comment: @Hardy i have posted the xml

Comment: The docs for that method mention that you should call `requestLayout()` and `invalidate()` on the parent.

Comment: @Luksprog which method are we talking about?

Comment: I think [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16719439/1405983) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502800/why-does-bringtofront-works-only-once).

Comment: @Hardy that last one relates to my problem but neither have thorough answers

Comment: Did you try to left the `View` visible ? I think you can change its alpha to 0 while still being visible. Visibility and alpha are usually 2 differents things, event if they are both related to the same idea.